# Android Unable to save data into second table

Tags: android, database, sqlite

I have two tables within sqlite database.
The first one gets data entry for shore. When I am trying to enter data to the second table (settings) I got an error:

```
05-20 14:25:04.941: E/Database(352): Error inserting uri=null gender=female     
age_month=12 age_day=05 age_year=1190 name=Tom
05-20 14:25:04.941: E/Database(352): android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConstraintException:
```

The Main activity method that inserts the data into the table is:

```
public class Choose extends Activity implements OnClickListener, OnCheckedChangeListener{

    private static final int SELECT_PICTURE = 1;
    static String selected ImagePath, Gender, BDYear, BDMonth, BDDay, bfNameת;
    EditText bName;
    TextView outPut;
    Button saveSettings, browseImageBtn;
    RadioGroup genderGroup;
    RadioButton male, female;
    DatePicker bBornDate;

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.choose_image);
        bName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
        saveSettings = (Button) findViewById(R.id.settingsSaveBtn);
        browseImageBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.chooseimg);
        genderGroup = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.genderGroup);
        male = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.Male);
        female = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.Female);
        bBornDate = (DatePicker) findViewById(R.id.bBorndatePicker);
        outPut = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.settingsOutPutText);
        genderGroup.setOnCheckedChangeListener(Choose.this);
        saveSettings.setOnClickListener(Choose.this);
        browseImageBtn.setOnClickListener(Choose.this); 



    }

    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            if (requestCode == SELECT_PICTURE) {
                Uri selectedImageUri = data.getData();
                selectedImagePath = getPath(selectedImageUri);
            }
        }
    }

    public String getPath(Uri uri) {
        String[] projection = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };
        Cursor cursor = managedQuery(uri, projection, null, null, null);
        int column_index = cursor
                .getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        return cursor.getString(column_index);
    }

    String ipath = selectedImagePath;

    public void onClick(View v) {
        if (browseImageBtn == v){
            Intent intent = new Intent();
            intent.setType("image/*");
            intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
            startActivityForResult(
                    Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select Picture"),
                    SELECT_PICTURE);
        }else if(saveSettings == v){
            BDYear = "1190";

            BDMonth =  "12";

            BDDay = "05";

            String bfName = "Tom"; 


            String pt = ipath;
            String bn = bfName;
            String bg = Gender;
            String bbdy = BDYear;
            String bbdm = BDMonth;
            String bbdd = BDDay;


            DatBas settingentry = new DatBas(Choose.this);
            settingentry.open();
            settingentry.createEntrySettings(pt, bn, bg, bbdy, bbdm, bbdd);
            settingentry.close();


//          Intent myIntent = new Intent(Choose.this, Tamar_appActivity.class);
//          Choose.this.startActivity(myIntent);

            //read the data

        }


    }

    public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup arg0, int arg1) {
        switch (arg1){
        case R.id.Male:
            Gender = "male";
            break;
        case R.id.Female:
            Gender = "female";
            break;
        }
    }
}

The DatBas Helper is:


public class DatBas {

    public static final String KEY_ROWID = "_id";
    public static final String KEY_SHOURS = "start_hour";
    public static final String KEY_SMINUTE = "start_minute";
    public static final String KEY_SDATE = "start_date";
    public static final String KEY_AMOUNT = "amount";
    public static final String KEY_SIDE = "side";
    public static final String KEY_KIND = "kind";

    public static final String KEY_ROW_ID = "_id2";
    public static final String KEY_IMAGE_PATH = "uri";
    public static final String KEY_NAME = "name";
    public static final String KEY_GENDER = "gender";
    public static final String KEY_BORN_DATE_YEAR = "age_year";
    public static final String KEY_BORN_DATE_MONTH = "age_month";
    public static final String KEY_BORN_DATE_DAY = "age_day";

    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "TamatDB";
    private static final String DATABASE_TABLE = "stop_watch_records";
    private static final String DATABASE_TABLE_SETTINGS = "settings";

    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 3 ;

    private TamarDatabase thdb;
    private static Context tcontext;
    private SQLiteDatabase tdb;

    private static class TamarDatabase extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

        public TamarDatabase(Context context) {
            super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
        }

        @Override
        public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
            String ctData = "CREATE TABLE  " + DATABASE_TABLE + " ( "
                    + KEY_ROWID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, "
                    + KEY_SHOURS + " TEXT NOT NULL, " + KEY_SMINUTE
                    + " TEXT NOT NULL, " + KEY_SDATE + " TEXT NOT NULL, "
                    + KEY_AMOUNT + " TEXT NOT NULL, " + KEY_SIDE
                    + " TEXT NOT NULL, " + KEY_KIND + " TEXT NOT NULL );";
            db.execSQL(ctData);

            String ctSettings = "CREATE TABLE " + DATABASE_TABLE_SETTINGS
                    + " ( " + KEY_ROW_ID
                    + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, "
                    + KEY_IMAGE_PATH + " TEXT NOT NULL, " + KEY_NAME
                    + " TEXT NOT NULL, " + KEY_GENDER + " TEXT NOT NULL, "
                    + KEY_BORN_DATE_YEAR + " TEXT NOT NULL, "
                    + KEY_BORN_DATE_MONTH + " TEXT NOT NULL, "
                    + KEY_BORN_DATE_DAY + " TEXT NOT NULL);";
            db.execSQL(ctSettings);

        }

        @Override
        public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
            db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + DATABASE_TABLE);
            db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + DATABASE_TABLE_SETTINGS);
            onCreate(db);
        }
    }

    public DatBas(Context c) {
        tcontext = c;
    }

    public DatBas open() throws SQLiteException {
        thdb = new TamarDatabase(tcontext);
        tdb = thdb.getWritableDatabase();
        return this;
    }

    public SQLiteDatabase getReadableDatabase() throws SQLiteException {
        thdb = new TamarDatabase(tcontext);
        tdb = thdb.getReadableDatabase();
        return tdb;
    }


    public void close() {
        tdb.close();
    }

    public long createEntry(String sh, String sm, String sd, String at,
            String tside, String tkind) {
        ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
        cv.put(KEY_SHOURS, sh);
        cv.put(KEY_SMINUTE, sm);
        cv.put(KEY_SDATE, sd);
        cv.put(KEY_AMOUNT, at);
        cv.put(KEY_SIDE, tside);
        cv.put(KEY_SIDE, tkind);

        return tdb.insert(DATABASE_TABLE, null, cv);
    }

    public long createEntrySettings(String pt, String bn, String bg,
            String bbdy, String bbdm, String bbdd) {
        ContentValues cv2 = new ContentValues();
        cv2.put(KEY_IMAGE_PATH, pt);
        cv2.put(KEY_NAME, bn);
        cv2.put(KEY_GENDER, bg);
        cv2.put(KEY_BORN_DATE_YEAR, bbdy);
        cv2.put(KEY_BORN_DATE_MONTH, bbdm);
        cv2.put(KEY_BORN_DATE_DAY, bbdd);

        return tdb.insert(DATABASE_TABLE_SETTINGS, null, cv2);
    }

    public String getData() {
        String[] columns = new String[] { KEY_ROWID, KEY_SHOURS, KEY_SMINUTE,
                KEY_SDATE, KEY_AMOUNT, KEY_SIDE, KEY_KIND };
        Cursor c = tdb.query(DATABASE_TABLE, columns, null, null, null, null,
                null);
        String results = "";

        int iRaw = c.getColumnIndex(KEY_ROWID);
        int iShours = c.getColumnIndex(KEY_SHOURS);
        int iSminute = c.getColumnIndex(KEY_SMINUTE);
        int iDate = c.getColumnIndex(KEY_SDATE);
        int iAmount = c.getColumnIndex(KEY_AMOUNT);
        int iSide = c.getColumnIndex(KEY_SIDE);
        int iKind = c.getColumnIndex(KEY_KIND);

        for (c.moveToFirst(); !c.isAfterLast(); c.moveToNext()) {
            results = results + "the id is " + c.getString(iRaw)
                    + " the sart hour is " + " " + c.getString(iShours)
                    + " the start minute is " + " " + c.getString(iSminute)
                    + " the start date is " + " " + c.getString(iDate)
                    + " the amount is " + " " + c.getString(iAmount)
                    + " the side is " + " " + c.getString(iSide)
                    + " the kind is " + " " + c.getString(iKind) + "\n";
        }
        return results;
    }

    public String getDataSettings() {
        String[] columns = new String[] { KEY_ROW_ID, KEY_IMAGE_PATH,
                KEY_NAME, KEY_GENDER, KEY_BORN_DATE_YEAR,
                KEY_BORN_DATE_MONTH, KEY_BORN_DATE_DAY };
        Cursor c = tdb.query(DATABASE_TABLE_SETTINGS, columns, null, null,
                null, null, null);
        String results = "";

        int iRawId = c.getColumnIndex(KEY_ROW_ID);
        int iBIPath = c.getColumnIndex(KEY_IMAGE_PATH);
        int iBName = c.getColumnIndex(KEY_NAME);
        int iGender = c.getColumnIndex(KEY_GENDER);
        int iBBDateYear = c.getColumnIndex(KEY_BORN_DATE_YEAR);
        int iBBDateMonth = c.getColumnIndex(KEY_BORN_DATE_MONTH);
        int iBBDateDay = c.getColumnIndex(KEY_BORN_DATE_DAY);

        for (c.moveToFirst(); !c.isAfterLast(); c.moveToNext()) {
            results = results + " the kind is " + " " + c.getString(iRawId)
                    + " the kind is " + " " + c.getString(iBIPath)
                    + " the kind is " + " " + c.getString(iBName)
                    + " the kind is " + " " + c.getString(iGender)
                    + " the kind is " + " " + c.getString(iBBDateYear)
                    + " the kind is " + " " + c.getString(iBBDateMonth)
                    + " the kind is " + " " + c.getString(iBBDateDay) + "\n";
        }
        return results;
    }

    public String getDataSettingsName() {
        String[] columns = new String[] { KEY_ROW_ID, KEY_NAME };
        Cursor c = tdb.query(DATABASE_TABLE_SETTINGS, columns, null, null,
                null, null, null);
        String results = "";

        int iRawId = c.getColumnIndex(KEY_ROW_ID);
        int iBName = c.getColumnIndex(KEY_NAME);

        for (c.moveToFirst(); !c.isAfterLast(); c.moveToNext()) {
            String[] resultsS = new String[] { c.getString(iRawId),
                    c.getString(iBName) };
        }
        return results;
    }

    public DatBas delete() {
        tdb.delete(DATABASE_TABLE, null, null);
        tdb.delete(DATABASE_TABLE_SETTINGS, null, null);
        return null;
    }

    public static class TamarDatabaseCursor extends SQLiteCursor {

        /** The query for this cursor */
        private static final String QUERY = "SELECT _id2, uri, name, gender, age_year, age_month, age_day"
                + " FROM settings";

        /** Cursor constructor */
        private TamarDatabaseCursor(SQLiteDatabase db,
                SQLiteCursorDriver driver, String editTable, SQLiteQuery query) {
            super(db, driver, editTable, query);
        }

        /** Private factory class necessary for rawQueryWithFactory() call */

        private static class Factory implements SQLiteDatabase.CursorFactory {
            public Cursor newCursor(SQLiteDatabase db,
                    SQLiteCursorDriver driver, String editTable,
                    SQLiteQuery query) {
                return new TamarDatabaseCursor(db, driver, editTable, query);
            }
        }

        /* Accessor functions get one per database column */

        public int getActressId() {
            return getInt(getColumnIndexOrThrow("actress.actressId"));
        }

    }

    public TamarDatabaseCursor getActress() {
        SQLiteDatabase d = getReadableDatabase();
        TamarDatabaseCursor c = (TamarDatabaseCursor) d.rawQueryWithFactory(
                new TamarDatabaseCursor.Factory(), TamarDatabaseCursor.QUERY,
                null, null);
        c.moveToFirst();
        return c;
    }


}
```

Answer (score 0):

> 05-20 14:25:04.941: E/Database(352): Error inserting uri=null gender=female
>   age_month=12 age_day=05 age_year=1190 name=Tom 05-20 14:25:04.941: E/Database(352):
>   android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConstraintException:

Look at your schema. In your code sample you declared **every** column with the constraint `NOT NULL` then you tried to insert `uri=null`.

1. Don't make all your columns `NOT NULL` if they might be `NULL` sometimes, or fix your code if they shouldn't be null.
2. Making every column `TEXT` is just wrong. Please take the time to research SQLite and make a proper schema. http://sqlite.org